# Django Email Configuration Issue: ConnectionRefusedError [WinError 10061]

Tags: django, email

## Question:

I'm encountering a ConnectionRefusedError in my Django project when trying to send emails. The error message is as follows:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Details:

## Context:

I'm using Django for a web application.
I have configured email settings in the settings.py file to use a custom email domain hosted on a Linode server.

## Email Configuration (settings.py):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.ip.com'  # e.g., 'smtp.yourdomain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587  
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True  
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_email@example.com'  
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_email_password'
```

I checked the email server status; it's up and running.

Question:

What could be causing this ConnectionRefusedError?
Are there any additional steps I should take to troubleshoot this issue?

I am currently testing the email on my local host before making the changes to the production server

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the allowed ports in Nginx:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
587                        ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
587 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I've made sure that Linode allows the 587 port
but when I try to type in the below code:

```
telnet smtp.domainname.com 587
```

I get the below error

```
Connecting To smtp.domainname.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 587: Connect failed
```

I also got the below error sometimes when I change the below:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.domainname.com'
```

the below error appears:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Are the ports open on the server?

Comment: @ArunT it should be I added the open ports in Linode server.

Comment: Are you able to ping that server in port 587?

Comment: @ArunT Yes results of the ping command are successful